# Main content going under the side menu in lower resolutions

Tags: html, css

I have a site with side menu on the left side of the main content. Everything is ok until resolution of the window goes low enough. On lower resolutions sidebar is going over the main content. I would like to have always space between them. How can I can I achieve that?

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pg2kwk5e/11/

And my css code:

```
header{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.fixedTop {
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 !important;
    left: 18px;
    top: 50px;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    float:left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top:50px;
    background-color: green;  
}
main{
   background-color: blue;
   height: 1500px;
   margin-left:15%;
   margin-right:5%;
   margin-top:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having main with a margin left of 15% have main with a margin left of 160px

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a solution for lower resolution screens though, however you can fix it by adding this to your CSS:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/abpjkvmb/)

```
body{
    min-width:750px;
}
```

Thus on resolutions lower than `750px` a horizontal scrollbar will appear and yoru sidebar never goes over the content